# Unexplained Nullpointer error

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I'm developing an android application where a user is told what letter to draw and the letter recognition is handled using gestures. I've got no idea why this is breaking. There are no errors being detected in eclipse but the logcat is saying it's a nullpointer exception. Here's my application code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnGesturePerformedListener
{
    GestureLibrary mLibrary;
    Resources res;
    String [] letters;
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    int i = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mLibrary = GestureLibraries.fromRawResource(this, R.raw.gestures);
        if (!mLibrary.load())
        {
           finish();
        }

        res = getResources();
        letters = res.getStringArray(R.array.LetterToBeDrawn);
        tv.setText("Draw the letter: " + letters[i]);

        GestureOverlayView gestures = (GestureOverlayView)findViewById(R.id.gestures);
        gestures.addOnGesturePerformedListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onGesturePerformed(GestureOverlayView overlay, Gesture gesture) 
    { 
        ArrayList<Prediction> predictions = new ArrayList<Prediction>();  //this methods asks to recognize the gesture against loaded gesture library
        predictions = mLibrary.recognize(gesture);

        // We want at least one prediction
        if (predictions.size() > 0)
        {
            Prediction prediction = predictions.get(0);    //get the 1st prediction auto generated for you by Android
            // We want at least some confidence in the result
            if (prediction.score > 1.0 && prediction.name.equals(letters[i]))
            {
                // Show the spell
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, prediction.name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My xml:

```
<android.gesture.GestureOverlayView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/gestures"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:fadeOffset="1000"
    android:gestureStrokeType="multiple"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        />

</android.gesture.GestureOverlayView>
```

The logcat:

```
04-30 14:36:45.716: D/AndroidRuntime(1558): Shutting down VM
04-30 14:36:45.716: W/dalvikvm(1558): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2a27ba8)
04-30 14:36:45.776: E/AndroidRuntime(1558): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-30 14:36:45.776: E/AndroidRuntime(1558): Process: com.gmail.Sheridjohn.letterchecker, PID: 1558
04-30 14:36:45.776: E/AndroidRuntime(1558): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.gmail.Sheridjohn.letterchecker/com.gmail.Sheridjohn.letterchecker.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-30 14:36:45.776: E/AndroidRuntime(1558):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
04-30 14:36:45.776: E/AndroidRuntime(1558):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
04-30 14:36:45.776: E/AndroidRuntime(1558):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-30 14:36:45.776: E/AndroidRuntime(1558):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
04-30 14:36:45.776: E/AndroidRuntime(1558):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-30 14:36:45.776: E/AndroidRuntime(1558):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-30 14:36:45.776: E/AndroidRuntime(1558):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-30 14:36:45.776: E/AndroidRuntime(1558):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-30 14:36:45.776: E/AndroidRuntime(1558):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-30 14:36:45.776: E/AndroidRuntime(1558):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-30 14:36:45.776: E/AndroidRuntime(1558):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-30 14:36:45.776: E/AndroidRuntime(1558):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-30 14:36:45.776: E/AndroidRuntime(1558): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-30 14:36:45.776: E/AndroidRuntime(1558):     at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1884)
04-30 14:36:45.776: E/AndroidRuntime(1558):     at com.gmail.Sheridjohn.letterchecker.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:23)
04-30 14:36:45.776: E/AndroidRuntime(1558):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
04-30 14:36:45.776: E/AndroidRuntime(1558):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
04-30 14:36:45.776: E/AndroidRuntime(1558):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
04-30 14:36:45.776: E/AndroidRuntime(1558):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
04-30 14:36:45.776: E/AndroidRuntime(1558):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 2):

You have

```
 TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
```

before setting the layout to the Activity. Your initialization fails `tv`is null. You need to set the layout to the activity first then initialize views.

And when you have

```
   tv.setText("Draw the letter: " + letters[i]);
```

you are calling setText when tv is actually null

http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r2/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/Activity.java#1884

Posting the source from the link provided by laalto. Thanks to him i corrected my post

```
1877    /**
1878     * Finds a view that was identified by the id attribute from the XML that
1879     * was processed in {@link #onCreate}.
1880     *
1881     * @return The view if found or null otherwise.
1882     */
1883    public View findViewById(int id) {
1884        return getWindow().findViewById(id);
1885    }
1886
```

Your stacktrace does indicate the cause its not unexplained as you posted in title

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 04-30 14:36:45.776:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1558):     at
>   android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1884) 04-30
>   14:36:45.776: E/AndroidRuntime(1558):     at
>   com.gmail.Sheridjohn.letterchecker.MainActivity.(MainActivity.java:23)

Comment: Thanks, I had it like that originally, changed it back there but it's still not working and I'm getting the logcat results.

Comment: @user2316046 it will work the crash may be because of a different reason  if you updated as suggested

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that you're calling `findViewById()` before `onCreate()` when initializing member variables. Your activity does not have a `Window` yet and `findViewById()` needs it.

For reference, here's the platform source for the line of code that causes the NPE: http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r2/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/Activity.java#1884 - `getWindow()` returns `null` there.

The `setContentView()` explanation given by other answers works but is not exactly correct. If you had the `Window` and was callind `findViewById()` before `setContentView()`, a null would be returned instead of an NPE being thrown.

The solution is still the same: Move the initialization to `onCreate()` after `setContentView()`.

Comment: i got it tv is null and then using tv to set text causes NPE. thanks gonna update

Comment: @Raghunandan In the stacktrace it NPEs here because `getWindow()` returns null. http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r2/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/Activity.java#1884

Answer (score 0):

Your Activity is calling `findViewById` before `setContentView` was called. Move `tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);` into onCreate.